# Make batch file to compile Assembler

Tags: batch-file, assembly

I am currently studying Assembler, and the version they use is rather old and well consists of 3 files, ASM.exe, LINK.exe, TD.EXE which are running via DosBox.
Basically I need to do three commands:

```
asm [filename].asm;
link [filename].obj;
td [filename]
```

in order to compile, not I want to make a batch file that I type:`run [filename]`

So it will just use the file name and compile everything.

Can anyone help please or give me a hint as to where to look for such info?

Comment: Although not related to your question, perhaps you may be interested in [this topic](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6281) that include a basic 8086 assembler written in Batch that _"can be used as an educative tool to learn assembly language basics"_. Using this Batch file you may write simple assembly source code and generate executable 16-bits DOS .com files without any assembler nor linker! **`:-)`**

Answer (score 4):

If you give only give the filename without its extension your batch could look like:

```
IF [%1]==[]  (
    echo WRONG SYNTAX: run ^<filename^>
    exit /b 1
)
asm %1.asm
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo ERROR: Could not assemble file. Abandonned execution! 
    exit /b 1
)
link %1.obj
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo ERROR: Could not link %1.obj. Abandonned execution! 
    exit /b 1
)
td %1
```

As [@LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) had mentionned in the comments, the extensions that allow path manipulation won't work. It is also safer to check the presence of an argument before starting execution and errorlevels before starting each step as [David wohlferd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189500/david-wohlferd) suggested

Comment: DosBox emulates an x86 processor as well a real Dos. Only if a different shell like 4dos is installed cmd like features will work but this excludes AFAIK the modifiers ~dpnxsz

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't think about that! I adjusted my answer

Comment: If the `asm` command fails, there's not much point in running the `link` command.  Perhaps checking errorlevels?

Comment: Off course...good point. Where was my head?? Thank you very much